# Как растянуть карту 2Гис по ширине?

Tags: android, html, java, webview

В WebView загружаю html код:

```
webViewMap.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://example.com", html, mime, encoding, null);
```

Отображается карта 2Гис. По размерам она меньше чем WebView. Как ее растянуть по ширине?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно у `body` прописать `margin` и `padding` в `0`.